# Sudoers - how to configure a lecture file config for a single user?

Tags: linux, sudo

I want to set up a custom lecture file for a single user on a system. I know how to configure a global lecture file:

```
Defaults        lecture=always
Defaults        lecture_file = /etc/sudoers.lecture
```

However, rather than set this globally however I would like to set the config for just one user. From reading the sudo man page I *believe* this is possible, but I'm confused as to what the syntax should be. Can anybody confirm if this is possible and how to configure this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sudoers file define the lecture file as follows:

```
Defaults:user  lecture=always
Defaults:user  lecture_file=/<location>/<filename>
```

... replacing `user` with the actual username.

I'd place the file to a location where the user has no access, or at minimum drop it in /home/user/.config and define permissions so that the user can't change/delete it.

Comment: Perfect, easy as that! Thanks so much.

It's actually for my own user, on a jumpbox, as a pop up warning in case I accidentally escalate to root and start doing stuff on the wrong box, so no worries over security/file modification, but all good.

Comment: Happy to help :-)